# How are situated the lines $k$ and $m$ in the space $E3$?

Tags: geometry, vectors, systems-of-equations, solid-geometry

Given:

k: $\left\{\!\begin{aligned}
&  x=1+2t  \\
&  y=-7+t  \\
&  z=3+4t  
\end{aligned}\right.$

m: $\frac{ x+6 }{ 3 } =\frac{ y+1 }{ -2 } =\frac{ z+2 }{ -1 }$

My decision:

Let

m: $\left\{\!\begin{aligned}
&  x=-6+3p  \\
&  y=-1-2p  \\
&  z=-2-p  
\end{aligned}\right.$

Then:

$\left\{\!\begin{aligned}& 1+2t=-6+3p \\ & -7+t=-1-2p \\ & 3+4t=-2-p \end{aligned}\right. \Leftrightarrow \left\{\!\begin{aligned}& 1+2t+6-3p=0 \\ & -7+t+1+2p=0 \\ & 3+4t+2+p=0 \end{aligned}\right.$

If I solved:

$\left\{\!\begin{aligned}
&  2t - 3p = -7  \\
&  t + 2p = 6 
\end{aligned}\right.$

And find:

$\left\{\!\begin{aligned}
& t  = \frac{ 4 }{ 7 }   \\
&  p =  \frac{ 19 }{ 7 }
\end{aligned}\right.$

but it is not suitable for: $4t+p=-5$. So the system of equations has no solutions.

And I get that: $k \cap m = \varnothing$.

But, do I need to check: $k \parallel m$ and $k \perp m$?

Comment: Only $k\parallel m$, which is obvious.

Comment: @Aretino But, why?

Comment: Really, why? Direction vector for $k$: $n_{1}=\{2;1;4\}$ and direction vector for $m$: $n_{2}=\{3;-2;-1\}$, but: $\frac{2}{3} \ne \frac{1}{-2} \ne \frac{4}{-1}$

Comment: @Aretino Why then are they parallel?

Comment: I meant that checking if $k\parallel m$ obviously gives they are not parallel, sorry for the misunderstanding. Moreover, I consider two lines perpendicular only if they meet, but you might be accustomed with a different definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$k:$ $(x,y,z)=(1,-7,3)+t(2,1,4)$ and $m:$ $(x,y,z)=(-6,-1,-2)+s(3,-2,-1).$

Since $$\vec{(2,1,4)}\vec{(3,-2,-1)}=2\cdot3+1\cdot(-2)+4\cdot(-1)=0,$$
we see that $k\perp m$.

Let $k||m$.

Thus, there is $\lambda$, for which
$$\vec{(2,1,4)}=\lambda\vec{(3,-2,-1)}$$ or
$$2=3\lambda,$$
$$1=-2\lambda$$ and
$$4=-\lambda,$$ which is impossible.

Id est, $k$ is not parallel to $m$

Comment: I have the same answer.